# Difference between automated stat_summary statistics and standard error by hand

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I'm plotting the mean and confidence intervals of a grouped variable using `{ggplot2}` and noticed that if I calculate the confidence intervals by hand or use `stat_summary()` I get slightly different results.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this discrepancy?

Reproducible code below (note - the variable `y` is purposely skewed to mimic my actual dataset, but wondering if this is what is causing the issue).

```
# Generate data
# Number of observations per group
n_per_group <- 50

# Generate left-skewed data
group1 <- rgamma(n_per_group, shape = 2, scale = 1)
group2 <- rgamma(n_per_group, shape = 3, scale = 1.5)
group3 <- rgamma(n_per_group, shape = 4, scale = 2)

# Combine data into a single data frame
df <- data.frame(
  y = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), each = n_per_group),
  x = c(group1, group2, group3)
)

# Using stat_summary()
df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, group = y)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", 
               geom = "errorbar", 
               width = 0.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 10, by = 0.5))

# By hand
df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(x, na.rm = T), 
            std.dev = sd(x, na.rm = T), 
            n = n(),
            se = std.dev / sqrt(n)) %>%
  
  ggplot(., aes(y = y)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = mean - 1.96*se, 
                    xmax = mean + 1.96*se), 
                width = 0.1) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = mean)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 10, by = 0.5))
```

Comment: How "slight" is "slightly"?  Are you happier with the results if you replace `1.96` with `qnorm(0.975)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ggplot default for the `mean_se` function adds 1 standard deviation, not 1.96. You can make your plots match like this:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, group = y)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = \(x) mean_se(x, mult = 1.96),
               geom = "errorbar", 
               width = 0.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 10, by = 0.5))
```

You can type `mean_se` at the console to see its definition:

```
# mean_se
function (x, mult = 1) 
{
    x <- stats::na.omit(x)
    se <- mult * sqrt(stats::var(x)/length(x))
    mean <- mean(x)
    data_frame0(y = mean, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se, 
        .size = 1)
}
# <bytecode: 0x10bd2b7d8>
# <environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

Comment: Interesting how the `mean_se` function calls `stats::var()`, which calls a C function, and then uses `sqrt()`, rather than using `stats::sd()` directly (which ends up calling `var()` anyway)

Comment: Yes, a quick benchmark on my machine has `sqrt(var())` a tiny bit faster than `sd()`--about 0.2 ms faster on input sized 1M--and I bet that's the reason it is used here.

Comment: Love to see these optimizations